# $(document).on('click', '#preparingforimport', function() used the first selected filter attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have this function in jquery.

```
$(document).on('click', '.filterBtn', function() {
    let filter = $('#status').find(":selected").val();
    $('#preparingforimport').attr('data-filter', filter)
});
```

which get the current filter and used it as data attribute for another dropdown, that if that dropdown is clicked it will execute this code.

```
$(document).on('click', '#preparingforimport', function() {
    let filter = $(this).data('filter');

    if (filter == 'unshipped') {
        swal({
            title: 'You are about to export shipments',
            text:  "Do you want to process all the unshipped data exported?",
            type:  'warning',
            showCancelButton:   true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#546220',
            confirmButtonText:  'Yes',
            cancelButtonColor:  '#d33',
            cancelButtonText:   'No',
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                let tr       = $('#ShipmentsDataTable').find('tr');
                let shipment = [], a, href, id;

                for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                    a    = $(tr[i]).find('td:first-child > a');
                    href = a.attr('href');

                    if (href != undefined) {
                        id = href.split('/')[4];
                        shipment.push(id);
                    }
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'/shipment/markprocess',
                    data: {
                        _token: $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'),
                        shipments: shipment
                    },
                    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (response.message) {
                            themeNotify(response);
                            $("#status").val("in-process");
                            $('.filterBtn').trigger('click');
                        }
                        $('.buttons-csv').trigger('click');
                    },
                    error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        themeNotify(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    }

    else {
        $('.buttons-csv').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Problem is that when the user chose another filter and click again `.filterBtn` it will set another data attribute in another dropdown successfully. But `$(document).on('click', '#preparingforimport', function()` used the first selected filter attribute value in `data-filter` always even if how many time i chose another filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
$('#preparingforimport').attr('data-filter', filter)
```

with:

```
$('#preparingforimport').data('filter', filter)
```

Explanation:

- the first statement changes the HTML attribute of the element, but doesn't update the value that jQuery stores internally,
- the second one, which is like the `.prop` equivalent for `data-`
  attributes, does.

Or, as the [jQuery doc page](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) puts it:

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery).